# Storing data in map<string, vector<std::pair<string, string>>> c++98

Tags: c++, string, file, dictionary, c++98

I have file named `Bird.lst`. I am trying to read its contents and store the data in a `map<string, vector<pair<string, string>>>`. The idea is to store the bird's name in the `string` and its attribute values in the `vector`.

Also, there are some attributes that I don't need (`vaccinated`, `babies`, `sale`). While inserting into the `map`, I have to check to not insert these attributes.

Where the attributes didn't got added, but while displaying, the `map` contents there are displaying empty spaces. I want to get rid of the empty lines from the `map`.

My `map` content should be seen as below. please help.

```
parrot.sh   ---->  eat    yes
                   fly    yes
```

Bird.lst

```
parrot.sh
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
babies      no
fly         yes
sale        no

pigeon.sh
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
fly         yes
babies      yes
sale        yes

duck.sh
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
fly         no
sale        yes
babies      no

flammingo.sh
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
fly         yes
sale        no
babies      no

eagle.sh
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
babies      no
fly         yes
```

Code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> attribute_pair;
typedef std::vector<attribute_pair> attribute_vector;
typedef std::map<std::string,attribute_vector> bird_map;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("Bird.lst");

    bird_map birds;
    std::string key;
    while(std::getline(file,key))
    {
        attribute_vector attributes;
        std::string value;
        while(std::getline(file,value))
        {
            // in case it has windows encoding with end-of-line = \r\n
            if (!value.empty() &&
                value[value.size()-1] == '\r')
            {
                value.erase(value.size() - 1);
            }

            // if we found the empty string
            if(value.empty())
            {
                break;
            }

            // now split the value into an attribute and a flag
            attribute_pair attribute;
            std::istringstream ss(value);
            if(value.find("vaccinated") == std::string::npos && value.find("babies") == std::string::npos && value.find("sale") == std::string::npos)
            ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second;

            // save the value into the vector
            attributes.push_back(attribute);
        }
        // save the bird into the map
        birds[key] = attributes;
    }

    // now print the data we collected
    for(bird_map::iterator bird = birds.begin();
        bird != birds.end();
        bird++)
    {
        std::cout << bird->first << "\n";
        for(attribute_vector::iterator attribute = bird->second.begin();
            attribute != bird->second.end();
            attribute++)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << attribute->first
                      << "   " << attribute->second
                      << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output from the above code:

```
duck.sh

   eat   yes
   fly   no



eagle.sh

   eat   yes

   fly   yes

flammingo.sh

   eat   yes
   fly   yes



parrot.sh

   eat   yes

   fly   yes


pigeon.sh

   eat   yes
   fly   yes
```

Comment: @Sopel what is terrifying to you might be the best attempt of a beginner. Better don't use such strong words, there are nicer ways to convey the same message

Comment: does `value.find("vaccinated") == std::string::npos && value.find("babies") == std::string::npos && value.find("sale") == std::string::npos` do what you want it to do? attributes are only populated if the line doesn't contain any of `vaccinated`, `babies` and `sale`. Even if the attributes structure isn't populated from a line it is still added to the map (causing the empty lines in your output)

Comment: @AlanBirtles i am trying to avoid inserting these values into map  ```vaccinated```, ```babies``` and ```sale```  using this line of code  ```value.find("vaccinated") == std::string::npos && value.find("babies") == std::string::npos && value.find("sale") == std::string::npos```

Comment: when you encounter an empty entry you `break` from the inner loop, but then you add the still empty `attribute` to the map anyhow

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number encounter an empty value from the file ```Bird.lst``` i am breaking it. after that i want certain attribute values which shouldnt be part of my map i am trying to eliminate it ```value.find("vaccinated") == std::string::npos && value.find("babies") == std::string::npos && value.find("sale") == std::string::npos``` using this piece of code. At that point of time some empty values are getting inserted.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number anyways your comment helped me where i need to look into. i have added a check before adding values into vector i,e value in map . i have put a check before inserting into vector to check for whether is string is empty or not. it worked  .. Thanks a alot

Comment: @AmithKotian Is there a particular reason you chose to use a `vector<pair<string,string>>` instead of a `map<string,string>`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau hmm, yes i would have gone with ```map<string, string>``` the reason i preferred to go with ```vector <pair<string, string>>>``` for the easier accessibility of attribute values separately . i,e from example ```eat   yes```  ```fly   no```

Comment: @AmithKotian Using a `map` is easier to use when accessing key/value pairs, eg: `birds["parrot.sh"]["eat"]` vs `birds["parrot.sh"][some_index].second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are parsing a `value` string into an `attribute_pair`, you are looking for specific attributes to ignore, and if you find one then you don't parse the `value`, but you are still inserting the *empty* `attribute_pair` into the `attributes` vector.  That is where the empty lines in your output are coming from.

Change this:

```cpp
// now split the value into an attribute and a flag
attribute_pair attribute;
std::istringstream ss(value);
if(value.find("vaccinated") == std::string::npos && value.find("babies") == std::string::npos && value.find("sale") == std::string::npos)
ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second;

// save the value into the vector
attributes.push_back(attribute);
```

To this instead:

```cpp
// now split the value into an attribute and a flag
attribute_pair attribute;
std::istringstream ss(value);
ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second;
if(attribute.first != "vaccinated" && attribute.first != "babies" && attribute.first != "sale") {
    // save the value into the vector
    attributes.push_back(attribute);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/bzZ9Pg)

That being said, you might consider [using a `map<string,string>` instead of a `vector<pair<string,string>>`](https://ideone.com/au45sA), unless you have a requirement to preserve the original order of the attributes of each bird (you are not preserving the order of the birds themselves, since `std::map` is sorted).

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting into map<key, value> here value is vector<pair<string, string>> > add addition check if value vector string is not empty.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> attribute_pair;
typedef std::vector<attribute_pair> attribute_vector;
typedef std::map<std::string,attribute_vector> bird_map;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("Bird.lst");

    bird_map birds;
    std::string key;
    while(std::getline(file,key))
    {
        attribute_vector attributes;
        std::string value;
        while(std::getline(file,value))
        {
            // in case it has windows encoding with end-of-line = \r\n
            if (!value.empty() &&
                value[value.size()-1] == '\r')
            {
                value.erase(value.size() - 1);
            }

            // if we found the empty string
            if(value.empty())
            {
                break;
            }

            // now split the value into an attribute and a flag
            attribute_pair attribute;
            std::istringstream ss(value);
            if(value.find("vaccinated") == std::string::npos && value.find("babies") == std::string::npos && value.find("sale") == std::string::npos)
            ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second;
            
            if(!attribute.first.empty())  //check the attribute value is empty or not before inserting into attributes vector
            // save the value into the vector
            attributes.push_back(attribute);
        }
        // save the bird into the map
        birds[key] = attributes;
    }

    // now print the data we collected
    for(bird_map::iterator bird = birds.begin();
        bird != birds.end();
        bird++)
    {
        std::cout << bird->first << "\n";
        for(attribute_vector::iterator attribute = bird->second.begin();
            attribute != bird->second.end();
            attribute++)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << attribute->first
                      << "   " << attribute->second
                      << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```